# Google App Script throwing a #REF error when exporting a PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a app script that works perfectly and exports a PDF from a organic sheet within a spreadsheet.

The problem is that the spreadsheet copies and throws a `#REF error` in all the `cells`.

Is there any way around this? I did see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992181/copy-value-and-format-to-new-sheet-in-google-sheets-using-a-script) but I couldn't work my way around it. Code below:

I would assume one needs to use the range. Copy to function? but I couldn't figure it out.

```
// Simple function to send Weekly Status Sheets to contacts listed on the "Contacts" sheet in the MPD.

// Load a menu item called "Project Admin" with a submenu item called "Send Status"
// Running this, sends the currently open sheet, as a PDF attachment
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Send Status", functionName:"exportSomeSheets"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Project Admin', submenu);  
}

function exportSomeSheets() {
  // Set the Active Spreadsheet so we don't forget
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set the message to attach to the email.
  var message = "Daily Sales Snapshot"; // Could make it a pop-up perhaps, but out of wine today

  // Get Project Name from Cell A1
  var projectname = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("A1:A1").getValues(); 
  // Get Reporting Period from Cell B3
  var period = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("B3:B3").getValues(); 
  // Construct the Subject Line
  var subject = projectname + " - Daily Status Sheet - " + period;


  // Get contact details from "Contacts" sheet and construct To: Header
  // Would be nice to include "Name" as well, to make contacts look prettier, one day.
  var contacts = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var numRows = contacts.getLastRow();
  var emailTo = contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues();

  // Google scripts can't export just one Sheet from a Spreadsheet
  // So we have this disgusting hack

  // Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);

  //create temp sheet that lets us copy the values
  sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var temp = originalSpreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet(); 

  //copy the values
  range = temp.getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true}); 

  //copy the values to a new spreadsheet
  temp.copyTo(newSpreadsheet); 
  //delete our temp sheet.
  ss.deleteSheet(temp); 

  // Find and delete the default "Sheet 1", after the copy to avoid triggering an apocalypse
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  // Make zee PDF, currently called "Weekly status.pdf"
  // When I'm smart, filename will include a date and project name
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Daily Status.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send the freshly constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});

  // Delete the wasted sheet we created, so our Drive stays tidy.
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to do that in an automated fashion within the script? I'm looking to setup a daily time trigger for this script and email it out to a few people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export Single Sheet to PDF in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335143/export-single-sheet-to-pdf-in-apps-script)

Comment: Do not forget to do your research before posting new questions! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch ! this makes total sense thanks to the rest who took the time to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me if any unfortunate soul lands on this page.

```
   // Simple function to send Weekly Status Sheets to contacts listed on the "Contacts" sheet in the MPD.

// Load a menu item called "Project Admin" with a submenu item called "Send Status"
// Running this, sends the currently open sheet, as a PDF attachment
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Send Status", functionName:"exportSomeSheets"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Project Admin', submenu);  
}

function exportSomeSheets() {
  // Set the Active Spreadsheet so we don't forget
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set the message to attach to the email.
  var message = "Daily Sales Snapshot"; // Could make it a pop-up perhaps, but out of wine today

  // Get Project Name from Cell A1
  var projectname = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("H1:H1").getValues(); 
  // Get Reporting Period from Cell B3
  var period = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("B3:B3").getValues(); 
  // Construct the Subject Line
  var subject = projectname + " - Daily Status Sheet - " + period;


  // Get contact details from "Contacts" sheet and construct To: Header
  // Would be nice to include "Name" as well, to make contacts look prettier, one day.
  var contacts = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var numRows = contacts.getLastRow();
  var emailTo = contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues();

  // Google scripts can't export just one Sheet from a Spreadsheet
  // So we have this disgusting hack

var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = newSpreadsheet.getSheets;
  for (var i = 5; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName) {
      sheet[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }

  // Make zee PDF, currently called "Weekly status.pdf"
  // When I'm smart, filename will include a date and project name
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Daily Status.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send the freshly constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});


}
```

Comment: Make sure you call `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after all your "write" commands, to require that they are performed before the next statement. (Google will batch certain calls to improve efficiency)